# How do I get a file to be recognized as a module in python

Tags: python

Here is the situation. I created a directory structure as follows

pymaster
----------file1.py
pymaster2
----------file2.py

Neither the pymaster1 nor pymaster2 directories are packages. That was intentional.

I set a variable x=1 in file1.py

In file2.py I did the following:

```
import sys, os     
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('..')) 
# this added the path to the pymaster directory to my system 
#path. I printed it out and it was added.

import pymaster  
print(file1.x)
```

I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "file2.py", line 5, in 
>       import pymaster ImportError: No module named pymaster

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an `__init__.py` file (which is used in the making of a python package) you have to specify the actual file name. The following should work:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('../pymaster'))
import file1
```

Any python file can be considered a module. A collection of modules is a package.

Comment: That doesn't work. printing sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('..')) already showed that it was on the system path....

Comment: If it is already on the path all you need to do is `import file1`. Also, what do you mean by 'printing sys.path.append(...)'? I don't believe `sys.path.append()` returns anything

Comment: what i printed was actually os.path.realpath('..') and that demonstrated that it was on the system path. Still not having any luck...

Comment: The return value of `os.path.realpath()` is independent of what is on your system path. It's return value does not tell you if something is on your path or not. In fact, it can return paths that don't even exist on your system.

Comment: So then how would I go about solving this?

Comment: my mistake, I meant to say I printed sys.path

Comment: @A B: Why do you say it doesn't work? This works just fine; Matt's solution is correct. Please give the error that you get when trying it.

Comment: This is the error I get ---Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file2.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pymaster
ImportError: No module named pymaster

Comment: As per my answer: `import file1` and don't import pymaster

Comment: @Matt actually what ended up working was placing pymaster's parent directory on sys.path. This let me access the modules inside pymaster.

Comment: @AB Did you try `import file1`? Generally when you import a directory name you are importing a package and not a module. From your question it sounded like you wanted to make a module and not a package.

Comment: @Matt I tried the import file1. for some reason that didn't work. I understand that packages and modules aren't mutually exclusive since they can be considered modules.

Comment: @AB If running `import file1` didn't work then the directory that file1 is in is not on your path. Modules are packages are different but related. A module is a python source file. A package is a collection of modules.